# Flutter web throws error on same project but different laptop

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

So I just won a new laptop in a competition and now I am having some trouble migrating my flutter projects. I have set up the editor and migrated the important files in the code, i.e the lib, image, font, pubspec.yaml and web. But this app is now throwing the following error

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...
ERROR - 2020-12-29 13:08:07.845202
GET /main_module.bootstrap.js
Error thrown by handler.
AbsoluteImportUriError: 'file:///C:/FlutterProjects/xspectre/lib/help/Auth.dart'
package:dwds/src/debugging/metadata/provider.dart 154:9   MetadataProvider._addMetadata
package:dwds/src/debugging/metadata/provider.dart 133:15  MetadataProvider._initialize.<fn>
```

I thought it may be a problem with my flutter but it runs the default flutter app without problem. 
I also tried deleting the file but the problem just shifts to another file. I can safely say that this a is a problem with the help folder which provides me essential tools such as the auth service. What should I do? I will provide any code neccesary. You can find the entire code [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1g3dP97nfbbY-6URwx2aaYBkUVFZSHJWR?usp=sharing)

Comment: Try "flutter clean"

Comment: Close the browser window and then this commands; $flutter clean , $flutter pub get

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**The Error:**

The error is happening because when importing your new project, some `imports` in your `.dart` files are now using absolute paths instead of relative paths. In your case, this is happening at least in one `.dart` file that is calling your `Auth.dart`.

**Sloution:**

Step 1: Look at the top of all your `.dart` files, more precisely at every single `import`. You will have to change everything starting with:

`import 'file:///C:/...`

by

`import 'package:...` and add the name of your app

Step 2: Rerun your project and everything should work now

If still issues, then make sure you looked at all your files to ensure you did not miss other wrong `import`... also, you can run `flutter clean` then run a `Pub Get`

(thanks to melwinlobo18)

Please mark the answer if this was useful ;0)

Comment: Ye .. just removing the import of the path and reimporting the right one worked for me. Thanks a ton.